# coexistence of min-width and width

Tags: html, css

I'm having some trouble making `min-width` in `rem` coexist with a width in percentage. [When resizing this jsfiddle the outer right block is going under because of the min width restrictions.](https://jsfiddle.net/epnpk7no/1/) I'm wondering if there an easy way to go around this and still keep that min-width + width?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="first">
    </div>
    <div class="second">
    </div>
    <div class="third">
    </div>
</div>


.container{
    min-width:20rem;
    width:80%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height:50px;
}
.first{
    min-width:3rem;
    width:15%;
    background:red;
    height:50px;  
    float:left;
}
.second{
    min-width:10rem;
    width:65%;
    height:50px;   
    background:yellow; 
    float:left;
}
.third{
    min-width:7rem;
    width:20%;
    background:green;   
    height:50px;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make the website more responsive when viewing it in mobile devices try using css media queries

See a simple tutorial here [W3Schools tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

And if you really want deep understanding then this will be major help: [CSS Tricks - Media queries](https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

CSS tricks is going to be real helpful for learning anything around CSS